# Angular 2 Template with conditional (?) sentence doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to use a conditional operator in html template using angular 6

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-pages',
  template: `
<div [@myAnimation]="o.isActivated ? o.activatedRoute : ''">
  <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div> `...
```

When I put `?`, the code stops working

Comment: You haven't given much to go off of. What errors are you getting? What have you tried? Does `isActivated` have value? What is the input to `myAnimation` resolve to?

Comment: The values for `myAnimation` are toggling between an `ActivatedRoute` object and an empty string? In my experience animation states are strings.

Comment: I would replace `o.activatedRoute` by 'active' or any string representing an animation state, you are passing an `ActivatedRoute` object.

Comment: The error appears when placing the character (?) Apparently it is not possible to place this type of operator in the .... component.ts, if I create a separate HTML component and place the same sentence works